# VBS- String split multiple on multiple lines into array

Tags: regex, vbscript

I'm trying to create a function that will take a string which could be over multiple lines, e.g.:

```
"declare notThese
declare orThis

hello = $notThis@butthis$
butNot= $ButNotThis$

andDefNot = getDate()"
```

And search through it, pulling out `{string1}`'s from all parts like

```
${whatever}@{string1}$
```

and then pushing them into an array.

How would I archive this? Would it be through regex or is it simpler than that?

Also would it make a difference if the string renders on multiple lines like above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it through regex. Multi-line or not does not play a role in this case.

```
Function ExtractStrings(input)
  Dim re, matches, match, i, output

  Set re = new RegExp
  re.Pattern = "\$[^@]+@([^$]+)\$"
  re.Global = True

  Set matches = re.Execute(input)

  ReDim output(matches.Count - 1)

  i = 0
  For Each match in matches  
    output(i) = match.SubMatches(0)
    i = i + 1
  Next

  ExtractStrings = output
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via the Split function:

```
  Dim sLinesOfText As String
  sLinesOfText = "Insert multiple lines of text here"
  Dim aLines() As String
  Dim iLine As Integer
  iLine = 0
  
  aLines = Split(sLinesOfText, vbCrLf, , vbTextCompare)
  Do While iLine < UBound(aLines)
    Debug.Print aLines(iLine)
    iLine = iLine + 1
  Loop
```